# Can't access to trash?

Tags: linux, filesystems, gnome, nautilus

Whenever I try to enter into Trash Bin in Nautilus when a file is in it, an error message will display: `Sorry, could not display all the contents of trash:///: Operation not supported`. Neither `sudo` or `gksudo` work, and changing to another file manager (such as nemo) didn't seem to work. Any clue?

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: Trisquel 7 Belenos. Installed GNOME from apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

I backed up all my data and I reinstalled the distro, this time with the default graphical environment. I think it has all been a misconfiguration, so I'm closing this question. I strongly recommend to follow the 'default' distro installation tutorial if you are a beginner, and once you have your distro ready to go, tweak whatever you like (or use a VM). But always have an external HDD/USB near for backups!